# Why not export driver callbacks

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, driver

Why do drivers put their callbacks inside a `DEVICE_OBJECT` in `DriverEntry` instead of behaving like a dll, and exporting them?

Comment: The notion of dynamic linking is absent in driverland.  Chicken-and-egg, you need the OS loader to implement dynamic linking but you can't get the OS loaded without drivers.

Comment: Maybe I don't know something... But drivers are PE. Which means they are loaded with the loader. Which means that the loader is present before drivers. Could the loader not just walk to the export table and find whatever it needs? (I do not mean that drivers should be dynamically linked. It's just weird that completely different mechanisms are used.)

Comment: callbacks in `DRIVER_OBJECT`. possible export it ? yes. but more easy do this way. assume you want set single common entry for all `MajorFunction`. or we can create more that 1 `DRIVER_OBJECT` with different callbacks, etc.